# Картинка ico для свойства Glyph

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно установить на кнопку BitBtn картинку в формате ico. Но для BitBtn можно установить только bmp. Что делать?

Comment: 1. преобразовать в ICO в BMP
2. пользоваться нормальными компонентами
3. переписать BitBtn для поддержки ICO

Comment: Мне желательно без этого!!!

Comment: Тогда ваш вопрос сродни "мне нужен чайник, но чтобы был как веник, но чайник" ))

Вариант 4. Загружать ICO программно, выдергивать из него Bitmap, подсунуть в BitBtn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте ico файл в паинте и пересохраните как bmp. Если результат не удовлетворит - скачайте какой-нибудь редактор ico файлов, откройте, прожмите printscreen, вставьте в паинт и наслаждайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Переконвертировать [ICO в BMP](http://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/).